# Show the inclusion $(S^2 - x, I - x) \hookrightarrow (S^2, I )$ is not an excision.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $I$ be a homeomorph of $[0, 1]$ in  $S^2$ with $x$ a point in $I$. Show the inclusion $(S^2 - x, I - x) \hookrightarrow (S^2, I )$ is not an excision.
(We are working with singular homology here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give $S^2$ the CW structure with 2 cells of each dimension:
$$e_0^0,\ e_1^0,\ e_0^1,\ e_1^1,\ e_0^2,\ e_1^2.$$
Identify the interval $I$ with the subcomplex $e_0^0\cup e_0^1\cup e_1^0$. Then, $I$ is a subcomplex of $S^2$, and therefore $(S^2,I)$ is a good pair.

Let $x\in I\subseteq S^2$. Now, assume that the inclusion
$$i:(S^2-\{x\},I-\{x\})\hookrightarrow (S^2,I)$$
is excisive. Then, the induced map
$$i_*:H_k(S^2-\{x\},I-\{x\})\to H_k(S^2,I)$$
is an isomorphism on homology for all $k$. As $(S^2,I)$ is a good pair, we have
$$H_k(S^2,I)\cong \tilde{H}_k(S^2/I) \cong \tilde{H}_k(S^2)\cong \begin{cases} \mathbb{Z},\ &k=2,\\ 0,\ &k\neq 2 \end{cases}$$
since $S^2/I\cong S^2$ (the quotient is the CW structure on $S^2$ with one $0$-cell, one $1$-cell, and two $2$-cells). Now, by the long exact sequence of the pair $(S^2-\{x\},I-\{x\})$, we have 
$$\cdots\xrightarrow{\ \ \ }H_k(S^2-\{x\})\xrightarrow{\ \ \ }H_k(S^2-\{x\},I-\{x\})\xrightarrow{\ \partial \ }H_{k-1}(I-\{x\})\xrightarrow{\ \ \ }\cdots$$
I'll leave the following as an exercise: What does $k=2$ imply in the above sequence? How does this give you a contradiction?